# SFMC - How to trigger an email based on email form submit

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, journeybuilder, dynamic, smart-capture

I am trying to build the following journey.

I have a landing page (w/ smart capture form) that captures the customer's information. After they submit their information, an email is automatically triggered with an interactive form for the customer to complete their profile information. (Additional fields). After they submit the form in the interactive email, I want to trigger another "Thank you" email.

My question is:

I want to use the same journey for all this. The trigger is the smart capture, they then automatically get the email with the form. How can I setup in the same journey, another trigger for the interactive email form?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the Wait Until Event activity?  Have your landing page send an API call to trigger the Event once they click submit.  You can set the maximum wait duration to however you want to kick them out if it makes sense to not keep them in the Journey too long.  Such great functionality that was released this year in April.